# Vaadin7 table sort label column numerically

Tags: vaadin, number-formatting, vaadin7

I have vaadin table with multiple columns. One of the column is of label class

```
container.addContainerProperty(ID_COLUMN, Label.class, "");
```

and I fill it up like

```
referenceItem.getItemProperty(ID_COLUMN).setValue(new Label(new Integer(reference.getId()).toString()));
```

When I sort the table by clicking on this table, it sorts the data like

```
1
10
100
2
200
7
```

So, I tried to change the class to Integer, then it works fine, but I get the numbers with comma like

```
1
2
...
..
7,456
8,455
```

How can I have the data sorted numerically and no commas.

Comment: _I tried to change the class to Integer_. How exactly, like `container.addContainerProperty(ID_COLUMN, Integer, "");`? And `referenceItem.getItemProperty(ID_COLUMN).setValue(reference.getId());`

Comment: like `referenceItem.getItemProperty(ID_COLUMN).setValue(new Integer(reference.getId()));`

Comment: just to confirm it is `Vaadin7`?

Comment: yes, its vaadin 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out. I used Integer as class for my column and used following

```
referenceTable = new Table()
    {
        @Override
        protected String formatPropertyValue(final Object a_row_id, final Object a_col_id, final Property<?> a_property)
        {
            if (a_property.getType() == Integer.class && null != a_property.getValue())
            {
                DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(getLocale());
                df.applyLocalizedPattern("#0");
                return df.format(a_property.getValue());
            }
            return super.formatPropertyValue(a_row_id, a_col_id, a_property);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since i have been having fun with Vaadin `Table`.

There are property formatters, generators etc... stuff but in this case it might be easiest just to:

```
container.addContainerProperty(ID_COLUMN, String.class, "");
referenceItem.getItemProperty(ID_COLUMN).setValue(""+reference.‌​getId());
```